# Why is $SO(3)\times SO(3)$ isomorphic to $SO(4)$?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, exceptional-isomorphisms

Why is $SO(3)\times SO(3)$ isomorphic to $SO(4)$?

Comment: Since $SU(2)/\Bbb{Z}_2 \cong SO(3)$, you might be interested in [More on the Isomorphism $SU(2)\otimes SU(2)\cong SO(4)$](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608186).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This isn't quite true: $SO(3) \times SO(3)$ is isomorphic to $SO(4) / \mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{1,-1\}$.  (Topologically speaking, $SO(4)$ is a double cover of $SO(3)\times SO(3)$.)

The simple explanation for this is the following:

1. $SO(3)$ is isomorphic to $U(\mathbb{H})/\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $U(\mathbb{H})$ is the group of unit quaternions and $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{1,-1\}$.  Specifically, the action of $U(\mathbb{H})$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is by conjugation, where $\mathbb{R}^3$ is identified with the set of quaternions of the form $ai+bj+ck$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.  (See the Wikipedia article on [quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) for more information on this action.)
2. $SO(4)$ is isomorphic to $\bigl(U(\mathbb{H})\times U(\mathbb{H})\bigr)/\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$.  In particular, any rotation of $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be defined by an equation of the form
   $$
   R(x) \;=\; axb
   $$
   where $a$ and $b$ are quaternions and the input vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$ is interpreted as a quaternion.

One consequence of this is that the [spin group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) $\text{Spin}(3)$ is isomorphic to $U(\mathbb{H})$, while $\text{Spin}(4)$ is isomorphic to $U(\mathbb{H}) \times U(\mathbb{H})$.  Thus,
$$
\text{Spin}(4) \;\cong\; \text{Spin}(3) \times \text{Spin}(3).
$$
The statement you gave is also true on the level of Lie algebras, i.e.
$$
\mathfrak{so}(4) \;\cong\; \mathfrak{so}(3) \times \mathfrak{so}(3).
$$

Comment: Is SO(3) a subgroup of SO(4)? @JimBelk

Comment: @SRS Yes, in the sense that there are subgroups of SO(4) that are isomorphic to SO(3).  For example, the stabilizer of any nonzero vector (i.e. the set of elements of SO(4) that fix the vector) is a subgroup of SO(4) isomorphic to SO(3).

Comment: @JimBelk I don't see how you go from $SO(3)\cong U(\mathbb{H})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $SO(4)\cong (U(\mathbb{H})\times U(\mathbb{H}))/\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $SO(4)/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong SO(3)\times SO(3)$. I understand that $SO(3)\times SO(3)\cong U(\mathbb{H})/\mathbb{Z}_2 \times U(\mathbb{H})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ but I don't see how this helps? 

Could elaborate please?

Comment: @Emily_257 I'm using the fact that if $K\subseteq N$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ then $G/N$ is isomorphic to $(G/K)/(N/K)$.  In this case $G=U(\mathbb{H})\times U(\mathbb{H})$, $N$ is $\{(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)\}$ (isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$), and $K$ is $\{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$ (isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$).

Comment: @JimBelk Ah yes that makes perfect sense thank you

Answer (score 5):

On the level of Lie algebras we have that ${\mathfrak {so}}(n)$ are just antisymmetric matrices $n \times n$. It turns out that the six-dimensional space of such $4\times 4$ matrices decomposes into two three-dimensional subspaces that are each closed under taking commutators and each of them satisfies precisely the commutation relations of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.

Because exponentiation defines an isomorphism between a neighborhood of the identity and a Lie algebra, we have that the two groups are locally isomorphic. It only remains to check global properties, like simple-connectedness, number of components, etc., to be sure the groups are really isomorphic (and not just an universal cover of each other, say, as in the case of $SO(n)$ and $Spin(n)$.)

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\cong\mathrm{Spin}_3(\mathbb C)$. I will give a construction of the map $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\to\mathrm{SO}_4(\mathbb C)$.

The group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ acts on $V=\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ in the obvious way, namely $(g,h)\cdot(v\otimes w):=gv\otimes hw$. This action has determinant $1$, so gives a homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\to\mathrm{SL}(V)$.

Also note that $\mathbb C^2$ carries a $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$-equivariant anti-symmetric form $\omega(v,w):=\det(v,w)$. Thus, $V$ carries a bilinear form $\langle v_1\otimes w_1,v_2\otimes w_2\rangle:=\omega(v_1,v_2)\omega(w_1,w_2)$ which is now symmetric. This is $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$-equivariant since $\omega$ is $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$-equivariant. We have thus constructed a homomorphism
$$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\to\mathrm{SO}_4(\mathbb C),$$
which has kernel $\{1,(-1,-1)\}$.  Surjectivity follows from a dimension-counting argument.

---

By the way, the isomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\cong\mathrm{Spin}_3(\mathbb C)$ can be constructed similarly, by considering the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ on $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, which carries the Killing form: [Lie algebra isomorphism between $\mathfrak{sl}(2,{\bf C})$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3,\Bbb C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423419/lie-algebra-isomorphism-between-mathfraksl2-bf-c-and-mathfrakso3/4575066#4575066).

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another construction of the double-cover $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\to\mathrm{SO}_4(\mathbb C)$.

The vector space $V=M_2(\mathbb C)$ has an inner product $\langle A,B\rangle:=\frac12\mathrm{tr}(A\cdot JB^tJ^{-1})$, where $J:=\begin{pmatrix}&1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. (The associated quadratic form is the determinant.) Moreover, $V$ has an action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$, where the first copy of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ acts by left multiplication, and the second copy acts by right multiplication: $(g,h)\cdot A:=gAh^{-1}$ for $g,h\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ and $A\in V=M_2(\mathbb C)$. This action preserves the inner product defined above. Thus, we have produced a homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\to\mathrm{SO}_4(\mathbb C)$.

The kernel of this homomorphism consists of pairs $g,h\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ such that $gAh^{-1}=A$ for all $A\in M_2(\mathbb C)$, which can only happen when $g=h=\pm I_2$. Thus, we have an injection $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)/\{\pm1\}\to\mathrm{SO}_4(\mathbb C)$. This is surjective by dimension-counting.