# Dual anisymmetric tensor generates su(2)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

An anisymmetric tensor in so(4) can be split in a self-dual and an anti-dual part. The self dual tensors are the ones that satisfy:
$$J_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{abcd}J_{cd}$$
While the anti-dual satisfies:
$$J_{ab}=-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{abcd}J_{cd}$$
I've proven that they conmute with the action of so(4). Now the author claims that they each generate an su(2) so that $$so(4)=su(2)\oplus su(2)=so(3)\oplus so(3)$$
I'm trying to figure out how does he come to this conclusion. How can I get an isomorphism between each part and su(2)?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234451/transformation-of-self-dual-and-anti-self-dual-tensors-and-irreducibility-of-rep).

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85833/isomorphism-between-mathfrak-o4-mathbb-r-and-mathfrak-o-3-mathbb-r-o).

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708404/explicit-isomorphism-between-the-four-dimensional-orthogonal-lie-algebra-and-the).