# Is a complex representation of a Lie Algebra isomorphic to a real Lie Algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{L}$ be a real lie algebra for which I know the multiplication table. And let $\mathfrak{L}'$ be another real lie algebra (of the same dimension).

In my way of showing that $\mathfrak{L}'\cong \mathfrak{L}$, I ended by constructing a complex basis of $\mathfrak{L}'$ such that in this basis $\mathfrak{L}'$ has the same multiplication table as $\mathfrak{L}$.

**Question**: Can we say that $\mathfrak{L}'$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{L}$ ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we cannot say that $L$ and $L'$ are isomorphic as real Lie algebras when we only know that their complexifications are isomorphic.
For example, let $L=\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb R)$ and $L'=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)$. Then, over $\Bbb C$ we have
$$
L\cong L'\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C),
$$
but $L$ and $L'$ are not isomorphic as real Lie algebras, since one algebra has a $2$-dimensional real subalgebra, the other one hasn't.

References:

[Lie algebra isomorphism between ${\rm sl}(2,{\bf C})$ and ${\bf so}(3,\Bbb C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423419/lie-algebra-isomorphism-between-rm-sl2-bf-c-and-bf-so3-bbb-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Lie algebras ${\rm sl}(2,{\bf R})$ and $({\bf R}^3,\wedge)$ are not isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596479/lie-algebras-rm-sl2-bf-r-and-bf-r3-wedge-are-not-isomorphic)

[$su(2) $ and $ sl(2;R)$ are not isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590601/su2-and-sl2r-are-not-isomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Good answer. I was about to suggest the same pair of algebras.