# Covering spaces of $\mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{RP}^n$ for $n > 1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

The fundamental group of $X = \mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{RP}^n$ is just $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ when $n > 1$. So connected coverings of $X$ correspond to subgroups of $G$.  This has $5$ subgroups: the trivial subgroup, $G$ and $3$ subgroups generated by the elements $a$, $b$ and $ab$.

What is the covering space associated to the subgroup generated by $ab$?

Answer (score 4):

Think of the diagonal action of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ on $\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{S}^n$ (in other words, acting by antipodal map in both factors).

Comment: I'd just like to add that, in the case where $n=3$, this cover is homeomorphic to $SO(4)$.  In particular, $\mathbb{RP}^3$ is homeomorphic to $SO(3)$, and $SO(4)$ is the appropriate double cover of $SO(3)\times SO(3)$ (see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46131/why-is-so3-times-so3-isomorphic-to-so4/46135#46135)).